# Rename tag [artifactory]

Tags: support, status-declined, retag-request, synonym-request

For many years now JFrog calls Artifactory "JFrog Artifactory" to align with the names of other JFrog products. Most of the tags are also named that way (e.g. [jfrog-xray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jfrog-xray) and [jfrog-container-registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jfrog-container-registry)).
Please rename [artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artifactory) to [jfrog-artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jfrog-artifactory).

Per @1201ProgramAlarm suggestion, a synonym is fine as well.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80332/how-do-you-go-about-getting-a-sponsored-tag

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not seeing what that's relevant.  None of the other Jfrog tags are sponsored, but they do have a company prefix.

Comment: What other product would it get confused with if the name wasn't changed?

Comment: @DanisFiddlingbyFirelight I think they may have been at one point; see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38979659/2756409 it shows sponsored icons in the tags in the answer, but not in the question for some reason.

Comment: "Artifactory", as a word, seems unlikely to become ambiguous.  Maybe a [tag:synonym-request] would be sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

When I'm looking for ways to solve problems in Artifactory, I don't search "JFrog Artifactory".

I just search for Artifactory.  There's no ambiguity, so there's no upside in creating a new tag for this.

JFrog Xray makes more sense since there's a [JIRA tool called Xray](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211769/xray-test-management-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) out there, and you *should* be as specific as possible when searching for "Xray" anyway...